# change range for date in d3 graph

Tags: date, d3.js, range

I am trying to draw a simple char with d3. I want the x axis to range from 12:00AM to 23:00PM

the data looks like this

```
date    count
01:00 AM    331
02:00 AM    1693
...
22:00 AM    1675
23:00 AM    1726
```

I have this code for the x axis but it doesn't work

```
var margin = {top: 80, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%I:%M %p").parse;

var x = d3.time.scale().domain([0, 24])
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear(200)
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");
```

Answer (score 0):

Plz read [Axis.ticks property](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#wiki-ticks)

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .ticks(d3.time.hours, 1)
    .orient("bottom");
```